# What are the effects of a rude insult?

Tags: oh-sir-the-insult-simulator

Sometimes during an argument in *Oh...Sir!! The Insult Simulator*, certain insults will be labeled as “rude”. I haven’t been able to figure out what causes a rude insult, or if rude insults have any special effects.

What does it mean when an insult is rude? What are the effects of a rude insult?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to an in-game hint:

> **Continuations can be broken with “rude” insults that score 16 or higher.**

Continuations are when a conversation is put on hold by selecting *(...)*. Rude insults will make your opponent lose their in-progress insult.

**However, I do not know if this is the only effect**. I have previously seen rude insults score 15 points or lower, so a score of 16 is not guaranteed.